# How to get HTTPS URL from get_page_link()?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a below code in which I am appending a WordPress page URL using a `get_page_link()` function:

```
$message .= "Publish Page Url: ".get_page_link($post->ID);
```

The problem is that my site is `SSL certified` but this code is giving me URL with `HTTP`, not `HTTPS`. Is there any way to get a `HTTPS URL`?

Note: I have already setup redirect from `HTTP` to `HTTPS` but I need HTTPS generated by `get_page_link()`

Comment: use str_replace?

Comment: @Barry Short-term solution; I thought of that but that'll only fix _this_ URL.

Answer (score 2):

[Change your base URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41978418/5223757) to include HTTPS.

Short answer: Run the following SQL statement:

```
UPDATE wp_options
SET option_value = REPLACE(option_value, "http://", "https://")
WHERE
  option_name = "siteurl"
  OR option_name = "home";
```

This statement is untested, but it *probably* won't trash your  site if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You must supply redirect your http link to https. Therefore, http or https not be problem.

Comment: I have already setup redirect from HTTP to HTTPS but I need HTTPS generated by get_page_link()