# wordpress repoint the URl to WP directory

Tags: wordpress, web

I am designing a wordpress website. I am quite new in it. I made a mistake.

Generally the website points to wp directory which I mistakenly changed it to home. Now, it gives a 404 error.

I changed this https://sure2biz.com/wp to https://sure2biz.com/home.

Kindly tell me steps to point it back to wp.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to set site url/base url in wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41978418/how-to-set-site-url-base-url-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not able to acces your wordpress dashboard, go to your cpanel, PHP My Admin => Select your Database => Go to table WP OPTIONS => there you can replace URL

Comment: This answer would be more useful if it didn’t rely solely on the presence of proprietary software not everyone will have (cPanel) - a more generic query that can be run directly on the target database would be a much more useful answer.

Comment: Thanks a  lot. It really saved me lots of time and hard work. Thanks again